# What happens if action=""?

Tags: html, forms

This is my code snippet from smarty template. I'm not understanding where does data go after clicking on submit button? can any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="" name="manage_News" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="{$submit_value}" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The current URL... as you can see when clicking "submit"

Comment: It's definitely not PHP-related

Answer (score 3):

The request is sent to the current url. i.e. the page that displays the form.